Producer-Consumer Problem with Mutexes and pthread_cond_timedwait
I am working on implementing a producer-consumer problem in C where multiple writer and reader threads interact with a shared buffer. The buffer is managed using four pointers: start, end, read, and write. The goal is to ensure that once data is written to the buffer, it can be read by the consumer threads without causing data races.
To achieve this, I am using two separate mutexes: one for writing (write_mutex) and one for reading (read_mutex). Additionally, I am synchronizing the threads using pthread_cond_timedwait along with two condition variables: one for signaling when the buffer is not empty and ready to be read (not_empty_cond), and another for signaling when the buffer is not full and ready to be written to (not_full_cond).I would like to understand the general approach and best practices for handling the following scenarios:How to correctly acquire and release the mutexes to avoid deadlocks while ensuring data integrity.How to use pthread_cond_timedwait and the associated signals to efficiently synchronize the writer and reader threads.How to handle multiple writer and reader threads to maintain consistency and avoid data races in this setup.Best practices for managing the buffer pointers (start, end, read, write) in this context.Any guidance or examples on the proper use of these synchronization primitives and buffer management in a multi-threaded environment would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Itdoesn't make sense to use two different mutexes to control access to one buffer. Well, I was about to say that until I just noticed that you said it's a circular buffer. So what's the problem? You seem to have a good grasp of things.

Your question is broad—could be a topic for a book chapter—and you're inviting opinionated answers. That's not a good fit for this forum. "Good" questions here run more along the lines of, "I have this code <in-line code sample> and it does this weird thing <weird thing described, maybe with sample input data, and sample console output>, and I don't understand why... https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking
